# from main import * ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'main',

Tags: python, blockchain, bitcoin

This is my script, I am trying to run in vs code for generating private key and public key. So please find the below script and help me to run below script.

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pybitcointools

# Generate a random private key
valid_private_key = False
while not valid_private_key:
    private_key = pybitcointools.random_key()
    decoded_private_key = pybitcointools.decode_privkey(private_key, 'hex')
    valid_private_key = 0 < decoded_private_key < pybitcointools.N

print("Private Key (hex) is: ", private_key)
print("Private Key (decimal) is: ", decoded_private_key)

# Convert private key to WIF format
wif_encoded_private_key = pybitcointools.encode_privkey(decoded_private_key, 'wif')
print("Private Key (WIF) is: ", wif_encoded_private_key)

# Add suffix "01" to indicate a compressed private key
compressed_private_key = private_key + '01'
print("Private Key Compressed (hex) is: ", compressed_private_key)

# Generate a WIF format from the compressed private key (WIF-compressed)
wif_compressed_private_key = pybitcointools.encode_privkey(
    pybitcointools.decode_privkey(compressed_private_key, 'hex'), 'wif_compressed')
print("Private Key (WIF-Compressed) is: ", wif_compressed_private_key)

# Multiply the EC generator point G with the private key to get a public key point
public_key = pybitcointools.fast_multiply(pybitcointools.G, decoded_private_key)
print("Public Key (x,y) coordinates is:", public_key)

# Encode as hex, prefix 04
hex_encoded_public_key = pybitcointools.encode_pubkey(public_key, 'hex')
print("Public Key (hex) is:", hex_encoded_public_key)

# Compress public key, adjust prefix depending on whether y is even or odd
(public_key_x, public_key_y) = public_key
compressed_prefix = '02' if (public_key_y % 2) == 0 else '03'
hex_compressed_public_key = compressed_prefix + (pybit`enter code `enter code here`here`cointools.encode(public_key_x, 16).zfill(64))
print("Compressed Public Key (hex) is:", hex_compressed_public_key)

# Generate pybitcointools address from public key
print("pybitcointools Address (b58check) is:", pybitcointools.pubkey_to_address(public_key))

# Generate compressed pybitcointools address from compressed public key
print("Compressed pybitcointools Address (b58check) is:",
      pybitcointools.pubkey_to_address(hex_compressed_public_key))
```

Comment: ile "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Sam\PythonBTCAddress\key-to-address-ecc-example.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pybitcointools
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pybitcointools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'                                                                                 I am getting this error for above script,

Comment: For same code if I used bitcoin library instead of pybitcointools then I am geting Error [ private_key = bitcoin.random_key()
AttributeError: module 'bitcoin' has no attribute 'random_key' ]

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, code and errors are hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the title you are trying to import the **main** module to some other module, you can't do that. instead, do it reverse.

Try not to cross-import modules.